# Automate Data Entry in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, automated-tests, data-entry

There is a small webpage with 2 text boxes and 2 buttons each to submit data in each textbox to the server. I have a list of values in a notepad which i want to submit through the second textbox automatically.

I believe it will work something like... copies the first line and paste it in the second box and press submit.. once done repeats the process for all lines in the notepad...

I have been trying to develop a windows application using c# but to no avail this far.

All i want is to automate this process... and looking forward for HELP !!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.. did it through WatiN :)

after adding a reference to the project.. i used the mentioned code

```
    private void btnComplete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "";    
            string[] Orders = txtOrders.Text.Split('\n');

                foreach (string text in Orders)
                {
                    // locate the Order Number (Completer) 
                    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("txt_comp_order")).Value = text;

                    browser.Button(Find.ByName("Button2")).Click();

                }

                lblStatus.Text = Orders.Length.ToString() + " Order(s) COMPLETED";

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).